# How to use async await with another API's implementation code

Tags: node.js, vonage

I have a user register function which is using async/await and I need to implement some code from another API. When I try to integrate it I get an error that I can't use await outside an async function.

```
exports.register = async (req, res) => {
  // some logic here

  nexmo.verify.request(
    {
      number: formattedMobile,
      brand: "My Brand",
      code_length: "4",
    },
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        // If there was an error, return it to the client
        return res.status(500).send(err.error_text);
      }
      // Otherwise, send back the request id. This data is integral to the next step
      const requestId = result.request_id;
      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(12);
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
    
      const createdUser = new User({
        name: name,
        email: email,
        mobile: formattedMobile,
        password: hashedPassword,
      });
    
      try {
        await createdUser.save();
        res.status(200).send({ user: createdUser._id, otp: requestId });
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
      }
}
```

Comment: You could make the callback function async, but then you laid yourself a trap because errors aren't handled and the outside code doesn't wait for the call. It'd be best to [`promisify`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) the third party function and `await` it instead of using a callback: `const result = await util.promisify(nexmo.verify.request).call(nexmo.verify, {/*options object here*/})`

Comment: You are using await inside `(err, result) => {}` callback which is normal arrow function not async function. You could make it async `async (err, result) => {}` to make your code work right away. Or promisify all other asynchronous calls as suggested above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the callback function `async`, and most likely wrap the entire code in a `try catch` block to handle errors.

```
async (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        // If there was an error, return it to the client
        return res.status(500).send(err.error_text);
      }
   
      try {
      // Otherwise, send back the request id. This data is integral to the next step
      const requestId = result.request_id;
      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(12);
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
    
      const createdUser = new User({
        name: name,
        email: email,
        mobile: formattedMobile,
        password: hashedPassword,
      });
    
      try {
        await createdUser.save();
        res.status(200).send({ user: createdUser._id, otp: requestId });
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
      }
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);//do whatever error handling here   
   }
 }
```